# Elastic search copy_to field update process

Tags: search, elasticsearch, logstash

I am trying to add copy_to for the existing index. For Ex:

PUT /my_index

```
{ 
  "mappings":{
       "my_type":{ 
            "properties":{ 
                  "user_name":{
                      "type":"string", 
                      "copy_to":["key"],
                      "index":"not_analyzed",
                      "include_in_all":false 
                   }
             } 
        }, 
        "key":{ 
            "type":"string",
            "store":"yes" 
        }
    } 
}
```

I have the data already in the user_name. When updating the mapping will these data gets copied to the copy_to field ? 
When i index new set of inputs will the new inputs only gets copied to the copy_to (key) field ?
Or do we need to do re-index to get the changes reflected ?
How to update copy to without re-indexing the whole document or can we update only the specific user_name document to get the changes reflected ?

Comment: what did you have in the my_type before?

Comment: its a document type in elasticsearch

Comment: yes, it's clear, what was there before you started to update it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mapping for a given field is "frozen" when that field is added to the index.  To change it, you need to reindex the data.